# Elements injected via Google Chrome extension don't behave as normal ones

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Google Chrome extension. I want to add a div element to a page via a content script. My code looks like this

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
const nodeToInsert = parser.parseFromString('<div id="myId" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px">Hi there!</div>', "text/xml");
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(nodeToInsert.getElementById('myId'));
```

It adds the element, but not the CSS: the element is at the bottom of my page (not at the position 100px 100px). By the way, it works when I add the element manually via inspect.

Comment: Insufficient information. Do you see the style attribute or is it empty / missing? Also, try with `text/plain`

Comment: I see the style attribute. You are right, it works with text/html. But I don't understand what is the difference between text/xml and text/html if the style attribute is the same. And also thank you for your help!